# I want to find duplicates in a file and add a character to the end of the line on the 1st match

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl

I am trying to find duplicates in a file and once a match is found mark the 1st match with a character or word on the end of the line.

eg my file (test.html) contains the following entries

```
host= alpha-sfserver1
host= alphacrest3
host= alphacrest4
host= alphactn1 
host= alphactn2
host= alphactn3 
host= alphactn4
down alphacrest4
```

I can find the duplicate using the following:- (I use $2 as the duplicate will always be in column 2)

```
awk '{if (++dup[$2] == 1) print $0;}' test.html
```

It removed the last entry (down alphacrest4) but what I want is to also mark the duplicate entry with a word or character such as:-

```
host= alphacrest4 acked
```

Any help is most welcome.

Comment: Strange html file...

Comment: just named it test.html. I should have called it test.txt for all the people who really care about its name. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to process the file twice. In the first run you write the dupes into a file:

```
awk '{if (++dup[$2] == 1) print $2;}' test.html > dupes.txt
```

The second run compares all lines against the file contents:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while (getline var <"dupes.txt") { dup2[var]=1; }};
  { num=++dup[$2]
    if (num == 1) { if (1 == dup2[$2]) print $0 " acked"; else print $0;} }' \
test.html
```

Comment: Hi Hauke, almost worked, just had to change the awk '{if (++dup[$2] == 1) print $2;}' test.html > dupes.txt to awk '{if (++dup[$2] == 2) print $2;}' test.html > dupes.txt

Comment: Sorry I should have said thanks for you help and very quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

This would be much easier if we had the entire file. Are you only interested in lines beginning with `host=` or *any* of the 2nd fields? For a general solution, try this:

```
perl -e '@file=<>; 
         foreach(map{/.+?\s+(.+)/;}@file){$dup{$_}++};  
         foreach(@file){
              chomp; 
              /.+?\s+(.+)/; 
              if($dup{$1}>1 && not defined($p{$1})){
                 print "$_ acked\n";
                 $p{$1}++;}
              else{print "$_\n"}
          }' test.html
```

The script above will first read the entire file, check for duplicates and then print each duplicate line followed by "acked".

The whole thing is much simpler if we can assume you are only interested in lines starting with `down X`:

```
grep down test.html | awk '{printf $2}' | 
 perl -e 'while(<>){$dup{$_}++}open(A,"test.html"); 
   while(<A>){
    if(/host=\s+(.+)/ && defined($dup{$1})){
      chomp; print "$_ acked\n"}
    else{print}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This could help:

#### One-Liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{b[$2]++; next} $2 in b { if (b[$2]>1) { print $0" acked" ; delete b[$2]} else print $0}' inputFile inputFile
```

#### Explaination:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { 

        ## Loop through the file and check which line is repeated based on column 2

        b[$2]++

        ## Skip the rest of the actions until complete file is scanned

        next
} 

## Once the scan is complete, look for second column in the array

$2 in b { 

        ## If the count of the column is greater than 1 it means there is duplicate.

        if (b[$2]>1) { 

            ## So print that line with "acked" marker

            print $0" acked"

            ## and delete the array so that it is not printed again

            delete b[$2]
        } 

        ## If count is 1 it means there was no duplicate so print the line

        else 
            print $0
}' inputFile inputFile
```